# Quicksort in swift with haskell style

Tags: swift, quicksort

I am implementing a quicksort algorithm in swift. Basically I want to achieve some Haskell style clarity. Here is the code so far I can develop:

```
func quickSort<T: Comparable>(list: [T]) -> [T] {
    if list.isEmpty {
        return []
    } else {
        let head = list[0]
        return quickSort(list.filter {$0 <= head}) + [head] + quickSort(list.filter {$0 > head})
    }
}
```

Can we improve this code to look like more Haskell style? What are your suggestions?

Comment: This should be posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com - this isn't what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the Haskell you want to replicate looks like this:

```
quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
quicksort [] = []
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let smallerOrEqual = filter (<= x) xs
        greater = filter (> x) xs
    in  quicksort smallerOrEqual ++ [x] ++ quicksort greater
```

You could add this Swift Array extension (which I [stole from objc.io](http://www.objc.io/snippets/1.html)):

```
extension Array {
    var decompose : (head: T, tail: [T])? {
        return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil
    }
}
```

and then do something like this:

```
func recursiveQuicksort<T: Comparable>(inputArray:Array<T>) -> Array<T> {
    if let (x, xs) = inputArray.decompose {
        let smallerOrEqual = xs.filter{$0 <= x}
        let greater = xs.filter{$0 > x}
        return recursiveQuicksort(smallerOrEqual) + [x] + recursiveQuicksort(greater)
    } else {
        return inputArray
    }
}
```

The extension gives you that little bit of pattern matching to get closer to Haskell, and the rest is pretty easy to see how it maps between the two languages. Haskell will still be more terse in its syntax, though.